# Use python in R-kernel Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I am using the IRKernel in a Jupyter notebook but I want to run some Python cells. I have seen [examples](https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/jupyter-notebook-r#gs.=LzBuwQ) to run R code while using the Python kernel in Jupyter, i.e.

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
%R require(ggplot2)
```

Is there a way to do the reverse? Something like

```
%load_ext py.ipython
%Python import pandas as pd
```

Comment: I think that it's not possible. `rpy2` is an interface to R running embedded in a Python process. The reverse has no sense. However, you can see [Beaker Notebook](http://beakernotebook.com/) . This software allows you to mix Python and R within the same notebook (unlike Jupyter which allows you either a Python or a R kernel)